# Batch processing in cypher Or upload multiple files from Neo4j browser

Tags: command-line, neo4j, cypher, load-csv

I am loading data from csv to Neo4j using the following query:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (e:Entity) ASSERT e.entity IS UNIQUE;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:/file1.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|'

WITH line 

MERGE (e0:Entity {entity: line.entities_0_entity})
ON CREATE SET e0.confidence = toFloat(line.entities_0_confidence)

MERGE (e1:Entity {entity: line.entities_1_entity})
ON CREATE SET e1.confidence = toFloat(line.entities_1_confidence)

MERGE (e0)-[r:REL {name: line.relation_relation, confidence: toFloat(line.relation_confidence)}]->(e1)

RETURN *
```

Could anyone tell the equivalent query to load data from Neo4j command line or a way to change the file name dynamically in browser or pass it like "file:/file*"...??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to process the same Cypher statement multiple times, adjusting one or more values each time, the APOC procedure [apoc.periodic.iterate](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_iterate) can be used.

*In your example, you'd want to perform the `CREATE CONSTRAINT` statement beforehand (and just once).*

For example:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "
    WITH ['file1', 'x', 'y'] AS filenames,
    UNWIND filenames AS name
    RETURN name;
  ",
  "
    USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:/' + {name} + '.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
    WITH line 
    MERGE (e0:Entity {entity: line.entities_0_entity})
    ON CREATE SET e0.confidence = toFloat(line.entities_0_confidence)
    MERGE (e1:Entity {entity: line.entities_1_entity})
    ON CREATE SET e1.confidence = toFloat(line.entities_1_confidence)
    MERGE (e0)-[r:REL {name: line.relation_relation, confidence: toFloat(line.relation_confidence)}]->(e1);
  ",
  {});
```

This query will execute the `LOAD CSV` statement 3 times (sequentially, since the `parallel` option of the procedure is `false` by default), passing one of the strings ("file1", "y", and "z") each time as the `name` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put all your files in the neo4j's import directory and then use a bash script to load them all :

```
#!bin/sh

for file in /Users/ikwattro/dev/_graphs/310/import/*
do
    curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -d '{"statements": [{"statement": "LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM file:///$file AS row ..."}]' \
        http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit
done
```

There is no standard way in Neo4j itself to specify multiple files to be imported.